# Message relationship feature in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table, relationship

I am building a message system where a `Team` can send a message to all `users` and a user can send a message to one specific `Team`

I am having trouble trying to decide the relationships between the `Team`, `Message`, `User` Models

My idea would be to use the same table for sending messages with the sender_id and recipient_id changing depending on who created the message and who the recipient is so the id can either match a user profile or a team id. The `type` being defined as either `broadcast` if its a message from the team to all users and a `contact` if the user is sending a message to the team that way when i come to list messages i can filter by type etc.

**Message table**

Below is the table columns i had in mind for the Messages table:

```
 Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('sender_id');
        $table->integer('recipient_id');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Because a team can have many messages and many messages and can belong to many teams I was going to create a new pivot table called `team_messages` e.g

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('team_messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('team_id');
        $table->integer('message_id');
    });
}
```

The relationship inside the team model would be:

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Message');
}
```

When it comes to the user to message relationship what would be the best option if the user can send a message and has the abilty to list messages sent too them from the team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using same table for both type of messages u can use polymorphism in eloquent

```
Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('message');
        $table->morphs('sender');
        $table->morphs('recipient');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

this will create sender_id,sender_type,reciever_id,reciever_type and u don't need a pivot table

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-morphs

for relationships u can do like

in Message.php

```
public function sender()
{
     return $this->morphTo();
}

public function recipient()
{
     return $this->morphTo();
}
```

in team.php

```
 public function sendMessages()
 {
     return $this->morphMany(Message::class, 'sender');
 }

 public function recievedMessages()
 {
     return $this->morphMany(Message::class, 'recipient');
 }
```

in user.php

```
 public function sendMessages()
 {
     return $this->morphMany(Message::class, 'sender');
 }

 public function recievedMessages()
 {
     return $this->morphMany(Message::class, 'recipient');
 }
```

for more info check https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations

MessageController.php

```
function create(){
  //if team was sending
  
   $team->sendMessage()->create([
    
    'message' => "",
    'sender_id => $user->id,
    'sender_type' => base_class($user)

    ])  

}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! so even if the team_id and user id's can differ in each columns will this solution still provide the best way to create and retrieve message records?

Comment: for example if you are sending an message from team to user them it will record sender_id as team_id and sender_type as team model and for recipient user_id and user model will be stored.so if u want to check a team sendMessages $team->sendMessages u will get  all the messages a team sended

Comment: thanks, so what if you are wanting to create a message to send/store as a team -> user would you do $team->sendMessages()->create() or is it $team->message()->create() am i misunderstanding?

Comment: How would i create a message record sent from the team to the user in eloquent?

Comment: in same table u can create a one more column message.